# angularJS: http request configuration url must be a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that takes an input from the front-end, and then concatinates that input into an URL that I want to get from wikipedia. Since I had problems with CORS, I implemented my $http.get as JSONP, and now I get the following error:

> angular.js:13236 Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url
>   must be a string.  Received:
>   {"method":"JSONP","url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&uselang=user&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages&titles=Maya+Angelou&piprop=name%7Coriginal"}

The thing is, that his error shows the concatinated url as a string?

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

This is the function I am calling:

```
//function to get author info from wikipedia
$scope.getAuthorInfo = function(author) {
    //remove whitespace from author
    author = author.replace(/\s/g, '+');
    //concat the get URL
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&uselang=user&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages&titles=' +
        author + '&piprop=name%7Coriginal';
    //get author info from wikipedia    
    $http.get({
            method: 'JSONP',
            url: url
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.author = response.data;
            //for every result from wikipedia, trust the extract as html
            for (var x in $scope.author.query.pages) {
                $scope.author.query.pages[x].extract = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.author.query.pages[x].extract);
            }

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
};
```

If you need additional information, please let me know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
$http({
  method: 'JSONP',
  url: url
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // ok
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // ko
});
```

`$http.get` is a [shortcut method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods) for `$http({ method: 'GET' })`, and expects the URL as the first parameter.

As you're using JSONP, you could also use the [`$http.jsonp` shortcut](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp):

```js
$http.jsonp(url).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // ok
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // ko
});
```